# Ways to shorten a switch statement with if statement commands

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm currently working on a restaurant app that allows you to select ingredients, and have the full nutritional data displayed. I am going to have about 20 ingredients.

Any way to shorten this?

```
function displayImage(image) {
  let display = document.querySelector(".display-ingredient")
  switch (image) {
    case "lamb":
      display.src = "images/" + image + ".png";
      lambObj.clicked = !lambObj.clicked
      if (lambObj.clicked === true) {
        meal.push(lambObj);
      } else {
        //unfinished code here
      }
      break;
    case "steak"....
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, store your list in an array or map...

Comment: You probably would not have to jump through hoops such as `lambObj.clicked = !lambObj.clicked`, `if (lambObj.clicked === true) { … }`, if you build your UI there based on using proper checkboxes. (You can still use images as labels to toggle the checkboxes.) Also basic accessibility would probably be much better.

Comment: @CBroe Hmm.. Might do that actually. Instead of display image in another div, just have nutrition opacity over on hover. Thanks for the tip! this is my first proper project so these simple things don't occur to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of your valid ingredients:

```
const ingredients = new Map()
    .set("lamb", lambObj)
    .set("steak", steakObj)
    /*...*/
```

And then simplify your function to just using lookups from the map:

```
function displayImage(image) {
  let display = document.querySelector(".display-ingredient");

  if(ingredients.has(image)) {
    display.src = "images/" + image + ".png";

    const obj = ingredients.has(image);
    obj.clicked = !obj.clicked;
    if (obj.clicked === true) {
      meal.push(obj);
    } else {
      //unfinished code here
    }
  }

 /* any other logic */
}
```

Which will work for all ingredients, you don't need to manually add code for each one, only an entry in the `ingredients` map.